# Compute the information matries related to normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, sufficient-statistics, fisher-information

This is a problem that I have trouble with.

> Suppose that we have $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{m}$ are iid
>   $N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right), Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ are iid $N\left(0, \sigma^{2}\right),$ the $X$ 's are independent of the $Y$ 's where
>   $-\infty<\mu<\infty, 0<\sigma<\infty$ are the unknown parameters. Suppose that $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{X},$
>   $\mathbf{Y})$ is the minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta=\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right) .$ Evaluate the expressions of the information matrices $I_{\mathrm{X,Y}}(\theta)$ and $I_{\mathrm{T}}(\theta),$ and then compare these two information contents.

The information matrix of $I_{\mathrm{X,Y}}(\theta)$ is not hard to compute, but I'm not sure how to deal with $I_{\mathrm{T}}(\theta)$. Also, the problem asks me to compare these two matrices, so I wonder whether there is relation between the information matrix of the original data and that of a sufficient statistic ( in my book the author mentions the one-parameter case, so I'm asking about the case when $\theta$ is a vector). Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read the tag wiki. Did you find out what $T$ is here?

Comment: $T = \left( \Sigma_{i=1}^m X_i^{2} + \Sigma_{i=1}^n Y_i^{2} , \Sigma_{i=1}^m X_i \right)$ ?

Comment: Yes, a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $T=(\sum X_i,\sum X_i^2+\sum Y_i^2)$. Because this is sufficient, you would expect both $T$ and the original data $(X,Y)$ to have the same information about $\theta$, i.e. the information matrices should be the same.